# How to pass values from an Ajax response object to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My ajax function is working fine. It retrieves multiple objects from the DB. All are `supplier_name` and `supplier_id`. The `response` object puts them in the correct element on the page.

Question: when you click on one of the options, how do I get the `supplier_id` to be put into a hidden element?

```
 $('#supplier_name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response, term) {

        var param = request.term;
        $.ajax({
            url: "supplier_search/" + param,  
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {

                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                       return item.supplier_name;
                    }

                ));

          //      $("#supplier_search").val(item.supplier_name);  THIS DOES NOT WORK
         //       $("#supplier_id").val(item.id);


            },//END Success
        });//END AJAX
    },

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><input class="form-control" placeholder="Type first 3 digits of name" name="supplier_name" type="text" id="supplier_name"></div>
    <input id="supplier_id" name="supplier_id" type="hidden">
```

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: @RyanZim Added html - cheers

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:

i have a  tag `<select id='cms_target2' name='cms_target2' onchange='javascript:cxChangeDept(2, this.value)' style='width:150px;'>`

and my javascript :

```
function cxChangeDept(level, val)
{

        var data = {
            level: level + 1,
            dept_code: val,
            type: "GET_DEPT"
        };
        cxGetData(data);
}

    function cxGetData(data)
    {
    $.ajax({
        url: "index",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            cxGetDataOK(data);
        }
    });
}

    function cxGetDataOK(data)
    {


     //do somthing with your data
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, whilst I expect your code is correct, it is not what I need. The JS autocomplete function dynamically creates a dropdown list of options and so therefore I am not using an HTML `<select>`.  When I select one of the dynamic drop down options from the autocomplete I need to populate my form with the additional values that are contained with the `data` delivered by the AJAX call.

Comment: Please give a read to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/215552, which will show how to format your code blocks so that they are legible.

Comment: Thank you @MikeMcCaughan. I got it

Answer (score 0):

```
function cxGetDataOK(data){
  $('#supplier_search').val(data.supplier_name);
  $('#supplier_id').val(data.id);
}
```